# php mysql encoding - fields full of question marks

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, field

I have some php scripts that read data from csv files and insert them to a mysql database. When I look at the table rows in phpmyadmin their data seems fine but when i open one of the rows for editing, the varchar fields become full of question marks. Also when I search the tables for any string the result is empty. the collation of the fields is utf8_general_ci....
Even a word like KAMZA displays like ��K�A�M�Z�A��

Whats the problem?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through